# Unable to install postgresql ubuntu with error initdb

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean, postgresql-9.6

I am using Ubuntu server. I am trying to install postgresql on it. when I try to start postgres using 
`sudo service postgresql start`
it result me into

```
*No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster"
```

and when I try to create cluster using command `pg_createcluster --start 9.6 main` (*9.6 is my postgres version)

The result is as follows

```
Creating new PostgreSQL cluster 9.6/main ...
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/initdb -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -- 
auth-local peer --auth-host md5
initdb: could not look up effective user ID 108: Permission denied
Error: initdb failed
```

I am not able to figure out what is the issue please help.

Comment: Do you have other versions of postgresql installed in your system?

Comment: `cat /etc/passwd | grep 108` is postgres?..

Comment: Hi @VaoTsun, here is result

`root@beta:/home/unicorn/log# cat /etc/passwd | grep 108`
 `postgres:x:108:112:PostgreSQL administrator,,,:/var/lib/postgresql:/bin/bash`

Comment: @JimJones No I have only one version installed i.e. 9.6

Comment: i it vanilla linux or docker? try running my cmd as user postgres, not as root

Comment: @VaoTsun I tried using user Postgres.
This is output
`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
initdb: could not look up effective user ID 108: Permission denied`

Comment: Permission denied
`cat: /etc/passwd: Permission denied`

Comment: try running as root `chmod 644 /etc/passwd` and try pg_createcluster again?..

Comment: Thanks Brother @VaoTsun, It Worked...... _/\_

Logging answer....

Comment: Hi @VaoTsun and all, could you guys please help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76272014/error-initdb-failed-postgresql-update-from-13-6-to-15-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `/etc/passwd` is not readable. I'm not sure which distro would require it, but it is a problem for `initdb`.

I believe fast solution would be running as root `chmod 644 /etc/passwd`

And follow with

`/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_ctl -D /usr/local/pgsql/data -l logfile start`

command